# Sql Server bulk insert from csv file, inserting same value on all rows

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I have the following csv file:

```
Brad,Pit
Michael,Jordan
Barack,Obama
```

I want to bulk insert this file to the following table:

```
MyTable
{
    bulkID uniqueidentifier null,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    surname varchar(50) not null 
}
```

Which must give the following result:

```
21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D | Brad | Pit
21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D | Michael | Jordan
21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D | Barack | Obama
```

In first column I want to store bulk ID, a GUID provided from code.

**How can I do this ?**

Comment: Primary key must be unique. There is no point in specifying bulkID as primary when it is same for all.

Comment: My mistake, sorry... you are right. Fixed now.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have a solution only by bulking inserting in a view with name, surname fields only (of MyTable). Then afterthat do an update of bulkid where bulkId is null.